# How can I determine, programatically, if a file is located on a network file system (NFS or SMB) in Linux and/or macOS?

Tags: file, nfs, smb

I'm writing an I/O test utility and as part of that I would like to be able to determine if a particular file is on a local filesystem or a network file system such as NFS or SMB. Are there any OS calls, or other techniques, that will provide this information? I have been looking but so far I have not found anything.

Comment: There's no portable way to do it. On Linux you call `statfs(2)` and check `f_type`.

Answer (score 0):

So yes, statfs() (and maybe stavfs()) seem to be the way to go. It turns out that on macOS statfs() is way more useful that either statfs() or statvfs() on Linux. Luckily macOS is more important for me. The f_type field (both platforms) and the f_fstypename, f_mntonname and f_mntfromname fields (macOS only) are what you need.